# Implement different behavior onClickListener for multiple elements but same class

Tags: android

So I have a class that extends `ConstraintLayout` that represents a single element with an icon and text.

From fragment I parse the response from the API and dynamically show multiple rows of the exact element described above but I change the icon and text for each one.

Each element need to have different behavior on click, so my question is how do I differentiate those elements so that I can implement different behavior for each one in the common class?

Comment: Use `.tag` property for unique ID of each element.

Comment: use RecyclerView

Comment: please, post code snippet here how you are adding this elements